# Load view from fragment when the fragment loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have button to go to (load) this new fragment

```
 buttonToFragment1.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                       // return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
                        Fragment fr = new FragmentOne();
                        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_awal, fr);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();


                    }
                }
        );
```

the current fragment (*`R.id.fragment_awal`*) now replaced with loaded new fragment (*`R.id.fragment_one`*) which has layout (`fragment_one.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00c4ff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ini fragment 1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the class is :

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

My question is how to load this `TextView1` so that I can do such :

```
TextView textFragment = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textFragment.setText(" new text");
```

which basically set text to a view inside the new loaded fragment.

**EDIT** : May I know who answered this question earlier??? basically he did answered this correct, I just somehow so confused. He just deleted the answer. I want to accept his answer.

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler, please undeleted your answer I wanna to accept it, you're correct I'm just so confused at the time because of being new in android development

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to inflate the layout and after that you can reference the `TextView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    TextView textFragment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textFragment.setText(" new text");

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Hello, and how do I get/call  this `TextView` in the button event?, I mean to load this view and set the text?

Answer (score 1):

`Fragments` are essentially view containers that contain a hierarchy of views. When a fragment is inserted into the view hierarchy, it must have an activity as its root. There can be more 0 or more fragments active at any given time.

In loose words, you're replacing the current view with the view of another fragment (`FragmentOne`).

To access the `TextView` with id `textView1`, you need to qualify the `findViewById` method with the current view of the fragment.

Change your fragment code to:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        // The findViewById method returns child views from either a Context,
        // an Activity or another View itself.
        TextView textFragment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textFragment.setText(" new text");

        return view;
    }
}
```